# Prefered way to customize and calculated values in Django

Tags: django, orm, signals

What is the recommend approach when extending some sort of save behavior in Django, such as saving calculated values?

I've seen people overriding the save method and I've seen people using signals.

What is the correct/most used/better approach for this?

Answer (score 2):

save(), delete() do not get called on bulk actions, signals are your only option then.

Answer (score 1):

I use simple approach. If need to update some fields on object itself - redefine save(). If need to work with other objects or querysets somehow - connect signals.